# Calculate $\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^ndz,n\in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm supposed to calculate $\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^ndz,n\in \mathbb{N}$ whereas $\partial K_1(1)$ is the circle with radius $1$ around $1$.

First I found out that $\frac{z}{z-1}=\frac{1}{z-1}+1$ so I can write the integral as
$$\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)dz = \int_{\partial K_1(1)}\frac{dz}{z-1}+\int_{\partial K_1(1)} dz= 2\pi i + 2\pi^2 i$$ by definition of the cauchy integral.

I have a problem now seeing, if this is even the right way and if so, how to work the exponent into my equation.

The first part of this specific question was proofing the "Walking the dog"-theorem.

Comment: It is incorrect, note $\int_{\partial K_1(1)} dz=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $z=1$ is the only pole inside the contour. The integral:

$$\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^ndz=2\pi i\cdot Res(z=1)$$

By defintion, the residue is the coefficient of the $(z-1)^{-1}$ term in the Laurent series.

$$\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^n=\left(1+\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{1}{z-1}\right)^k$$

Use the binomial expansion and we get the coefficient of the $(z-1)^{-1}$ term is $n$. Therefore

$$\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^ndz=2n\pi i$$

$$================\text{Alternative Method}================$$

Let $z=1+e^{i\theta}$, then we get:

$$I=\int_{\partial K_1(1)}\left(\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^ndz=\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\frac{1+e^{i\theta}}{e^{i\theta}}\right)^n i e^{i\theta}d\theta=i\int_0^{2\pi}\left(e^{-i\theta}+1\right)^n  e^{i\theta}d\theta$$

If we use binomial expansion, the only non-vanish term is

$$I=i\int_0^{2\pi}\binom{n}{1}e^{-i\theta}  e^{i\theta}d\theta=2n\pi i$$